# How to create attachment field in dxtreme?

Tags: button, devexpress, attachment, phonejs, devextreme

I really wanted my form to have an attachment field wherein a user can browse a file. I came to read the documentation but cannot find an example on how to create an attachment field. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: DevExtreme does not provide these functionalities. However, you can use the PhoneGap API to upload an image and record an audio file if you are using phonegap. 

Or you can try: <input type="file"/> and style it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, devexpress does not provide the capability to upload files, my recommendation is to use phoneGap API instead.

[PhoneGap File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html)
[PhoneGap Media API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media)

Also Check [FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) Object to upload or download files to and from the server.
You will find full examples in the link I provided.